# copy binded text using clipboard js

Tags: html, angular, clipboard

Im trying to use clipboard js to copy address.

Here is my html

```
<span class="td-label">Address</span>
<br>
<b class="capitalize onhovertooltip-300" id="foo" value= 'forward.address' >{{forward.address}}</b>  
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#foo">
<img alt="Copy to clipboard"></button>
```

Did I miss anything else ? Im using angular and i installed clipboard js using this 
npm install clipboard --save

Comment: Which version of angular?

Comment: This code works for me in Angular 5. Your problem is not with the code provided. 

Are you sure, that your `forward.address` is valid? can you see it's content in the HTML rendered?

Comment: Im not using angular 5, Im using angular 4